# Windows 11 Laptop is woken up by USB wired mouse despite mouse's ability to wake being disabled and wake_armed showing "NONE". How to fix?

Tags: usb, mouse, sleep, windows-11, microsoft

We have a custom Windows 11 laptop that has an external Microsoft USB wired mouse attached to it with the full Microsoft drivers for it installed.

In Device Manager, the mouse's ability to wake up the laptop has been disabled.

However, the mouse continues to wake up Windows from sleep.

In elevated **cmd**:

`powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` shows `NONE`
`powercfg -waketimers` shows 'There are no active wake timers in the system.'

`powercfg -lastwake` shows `Wake History Count - 0`

We tried re-enabling the mouse's ability to wake the PC up and then running in elevatd **cmd**:

`powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` which shows `Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse (Mouse and Keyboard Center)`

followed by:

`powercfg -devicedisablewake "Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse (Mouse and Keyboard Center)"`

followed by:

`powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` which shows `NONE`

And yet the external mouse continues to wake up Windows.

Even Viewer shows the following under Log Name "system" Source "Kernel-Power" and Event ID "507"

> The system is exiting Modern Standby
>
> Reason: Input Mouse.

How can we fix this so that this external mouse stops waking up Windows considering Windows claims it's not armed to wake it yet it continues to wake it.

Comment: That may also depend on UEFI settings. Please check before anything else.

Comment: @ChanganAuto can you please expound on this?  Which settings should we be looking at?

Comment: "Wake up" settings or similar language, as usual. In this case "wake up by mouse/keyboard".